# Where should I initialize my singleton in iOS/OS X app?

Tags: ios, cocoa, singleton, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to initialize my singleton object which stores and manages the application settings over the entire class within my app. Also, the singleton instance should be initialized by loading the data from `NSUserDefaults` upon launch. However, I'm not fully sure where I should initialize the singleton upon launch.

In Cocoa app, I first wrote the singleton initialization code within `applicationWillFinishLaunching:`, taking parameters from `NSUserDefaults`. However, later I found that this doesn't work properly if I also write the singleton initialization code (taking no parameter!) within my initial view controller, set in storyboard, because the `viewWillLoad:`, `viewDidLoad:` etc. of the class of the view controller are called **before** the `applicationWillFinishLaunching:`.

So now I'm sure I should write the singleton initalization code within `viewWillLoad:` **earlier than** `applicationWillFinishLaunching`, but still not sure whether it is appropriate. Specifically, I know the `NSApplicationMain` is the first method to be called upon launch, but it seems that the next method is not anything within `AppDelegate`, at least if you use storyboard.

To summary, what I want to ask are the following:

- What method from what class will be called after `NSApplicationMain`, if you use storyboard.
- Where should I write my singleton initialization code within my app? I want to initialize it as soon as possible.
- Does it differ between iOS and OS X app?

Comment: you could do it in `initialize` if you need it like, immediately

Comment: The beauty of singleton is that, from the singleton's perspective at least, it simply doesn't matter where you first reference the singleton. The singleton's `sharedInstance` code (or whatever you call it) should do all the necessary configuring, and wherever the `sharedInstance` method is first encountered in the code will do this initial configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Is it stupid to initialize it as soon as possible? I think it costs very, very little time and improves maintenance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize it when it's first accessed. Something like this, maybe:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    _instance = [[self alloc] init];
  });
  return _instance;
}
```

---

As a side note, if you're literally only using this class as an accessor to `NSUserDefaults`, you might want to consider using static methods instead.

```
+ (id)mySpecificDataPoint {
  return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"whatever"];
}
+ (void)setMySpecificDataPoint:(id)data {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"whatever"];
}
```

---

Or maybe a more well-designed way might be to add a category to `NSUserDefaults` for this purpose.

```
@interface NSUserDefaults (MyData)
@property (nonatomic) NSString *someDataPoint;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger somePrimitiveDataPoint;
@end

@implementation NSUserDefaults (MyData)
- (NSString *)someDataPoint {
  return [self objectForKey:@"someDataPoint"];
}
- (void)setSomeDataPoint:(NSString *)someDataPoint {
  [self setObject:someDataPoint forKey:@"someDataPoint"];
}
- (NSInteger)somePrimitiveDataPoint {
  return [[self objectForKey:@"somePrimitiveDataPoint"] integerValue];
}
- (void)setSomePrimitiveDataPoint:(NSInteger)somePrimitiveDataPoint {
  [self setObject:@(somePrimitiveDataPoint) forKey:@"somePrimitiveDataPoint"];
}
@end
```

Comment: Ah, I like the idea of just making the part of singleton implementation as an accessor to `NSUserDefaults`!. I bothered to load values from user default and throw it as arguments to the init of singleton... Thanks.

Comment: The question was tagged `swift` but your answer is written in Objective-C.  Perhaps you can update your answer with Swift code also?

Comment: @sbooth, Deleted `swift` tag. The question should apply both to Swift and Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

You init the singleton when you have to use it. So as Daji Djan said: lazy wins. Just take attention that, you should not do a long-run process in your `applicationWillFinishLaunching`, it should return as soon as possible.

If the singleton is not mandatory during applicationWillFinishLaunching, you should call it in viewWillAppear of first view controller if you need to initialize it ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

## lazy always wins

if you can get away with it: as late as possible :) AND always do the minimum needed (but do as much as is reasonable to keep your code clean!)